# powershell looping and storing content to variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

So I need my script to loop through an array and store the content in other variable, so I can manipulate it later.

```
foreach ($element in $machinesNames){
Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $element | select LoadIndex -expand LoadIndex
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2845
5750
5875
5944
5873
5828
5205
6302
5025
5655
6311
5626
5491
5621
```

How can I store above results in an array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign the output from a loop construct directly to a variable:

```
$result = foreach($element in $machinesNames){
    Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $element | select LoadIndex -expand LoadIndex
}
```

If you want to make sure that you always end up with an array, wrap the expression in an array subexpression operator `@()`:

```
$result = @(foreach($element in $machinesNames){
    Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $element | select LoadIndex -expand LoadIndex
})
```

Comment: Wow, sometimes the easiest things seems harder :)
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize an array by setting `$myvar = @()` then within your foreach loop add the content of your query to myvar. Your code will look like this:

```
$myvar = @()
foreach ($element in $machinesNames){
$myvar += Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $element | select LoadIndex -expand LoadIndex
}
return $myvar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize and add to an arraylist within your loop such as:

```
$ArrList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$ArrList.Add(Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $element | select LoadIndex -expand LoadIndex)
```

then return it anywhere..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ForEach-Object` to accumulate a list:

```
$results = $machineNames | ForEach-Object { Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LoadIndex }
```

If there is one output, it will be a single element; otherwise it will be a collection. If you want to ensure it's a collection:

```
$results = @($machineNames | ForEach-Object { Get-BrokerMachine -MachineName $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LoadIndex })
```

I tend to like this solution because it's a single assignment statement.